# Is there a way to have $args suggestions when using a template part?

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, visual-studio-code, arguments

I work in a WP project using template parts, as they are multiple buttons instance in this project i created a button template that can take multiple arguments as such:

```
<?

/**
 * Default button template
 * 
 */
$container_classes = $args["container_classes"]; //additional container classes
$button_type = $args['button_type']; // link | button | modal
$elem_classes = $args['elem_classes']; //additional classes for the button
$url = $args['url'] ?? null; //provides the url target
$text = $args['text'] ?? null; // text to display inside the button
$text_color = $args['text_color'] ?? "white"; // text color
$bg_color = $args['bg_color'] ?? 'cta';
$target = $args['target'] ?? "_self"; //target attribute
$icon = $args['icon'] ?? null; //If there is an icon, link to the icon
$modal_slug = $args['modal_slug'] ?? 'null'

?>

<div class="button-<?= $button_type ?> flex <?= $container_classes ?>">

{... All the button specifications and other logical checks ... }
     
</div>
```

I would now like to use this template in multiple sections. But with all those $args i would like to have suggestions when typing in the arguments in the get_template_part() function.

Is there a way of defining the possible $args in the template-part file as i've seen it being used in functions for instance ?

Exemple of predefined params for a function:

```
function get_template_part( $slug, $name = null, $args = array() ) {
    /**
     * Fires before the specified template part file is loaded.
     *
     * The dynamic portion of the hook name, `$slug`, refers to the slug name
     * for the generic template part.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     * @since 5.5.0 The `$args` parameter was added.
     *
     * @param string      $slug The slug name for the generic template.
     * @param string|null $name The name of the specialized template.
     * @param array       $args Additional arguments passed to the template.
     */
```

where the @param notation defines expected parameters.

I'm trying to have suggestion proposed by VsCode when using a template part and trying to figure out a way for the $args to reproduce the params behavior in the case of a function.